Yii2 env with Yii2 Schedule cannot read env value for console Controller
I use the following extensions.

https://github.com/omnilight/yii2-scheduling
https://packagist.org/packages/yiithings/yii2-dotenv

Then I have a controller located at commands/AutoReportSalesDailyController
class AutoReportSalesDailyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return int|string
     */
    public function actionIndex(): int|string
    {
       
        echo "ENV FILE: " . env('DB_HOST') .PHP_EOL;
        return ExitCode::OK;
    }
}


Yes, easily, I can execute the file:
root@php:/var/www/html# php yii auto-report-sales-daily
ENV FILE: db

But the problem is when using yii2-scheduling with cron.
For example, the configuration is in config/schedule.php
use omnilight\scheduling\Schedule;

$schedule->command('auto-report-sales-daily')
->everyMinute()
->sendOutputTo('/var/log/something.log');

The results obtained in the log:
root@php:/var/www/html# tail -f /var/log/something.log 
ENV FILES:

Why is that possible, is there any configuration that needs to be done again?
